# How to compare Scalar to Float

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compare the value I get from `np.max(err)` and `np.min(err)` to a float number, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

I've tried converting them to float by using the float() function, but that got me:

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Code:

```py
err = [evaluation[i] - Ytest_set[i] for i in range(len(evaluation))]

if (0-float(np.min(err)))<0.05 & (0-float(np.max(err)))<0.05:
       self.eval_pass = True
```

the goal is so for `np.min(err)` to be recognized as a float so that it can be compared to `0.05`.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `[0]` and `.[0]` actions?  It might help if you show all or part of `err`, and then also `np.max(err)` and the `min`.

Comment: Can you try `np.max(err).astype(float)` & `np.min(err).astype(float)` and then compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This much simpler code should be OK:

```
if -np.min(err)<0.05 and -np.max(err)<0.05:
   self.eval_pass = True
```

If not, than you probably have a problem with the definition of `err`
BTW: as `err` is a list, you don't have to use `np.min()\np.max()`, and use the plain `min()\min()` instead.